# Parsing JSON text having comma and quotation marks

Tags: json

I got an "Parse error" on the following JSON object. Wonder how to fix it.

> ```
> {
>     "Information": [
>         {
>             "nm": "Earn Goody",
>             "st": "y",
>             "source": "Internet",
>             "story": [
>                 {
> "Don't let the smile fool you. Sabine Lisicki is the proverbial "crazy guy in the fight," at least when grass courts are involved.
> Perhaps the only player capable of keeping up with Serena Williams
> from a power-and-movement standpoint, Lisicki not only kept up, she
> beat Williams, 6-2, 1-6, 6-4, in the Round of 16 at Wimbledon on
> Monday.",
> "Women's tennis had, like men's tennis, grown predictable recently, with either Williams, Maria Sharapova, or Victoria Azarenka
> winning the last six slam titles."
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

**Result:**

```
{
    "Information": [
        {
            "nm": "Earn Goody",
            "st": "y",
            "source": "Internet",
            "story": [
                {
                    "Don't let the smile fool you. Sabine Lisicki is the proverbial crazyguyinthefight at least when grass courts are involved. Perhaps the only player capable of keeping up with Serena Williams from a power-and-movement standpoint, Lisicki not only kept up, she beat Williams, 6-2, 1-6, 6-4, in the Round of 16 at Wimbledon on Monday.",
                    "Women's tennis had, like men's tennis, grown predictable recently, with either Williams, Maria Sharapova, or Victoria Azarenka winning the last six slam titles."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Parse error on line 9:
...imbledon on Monday.",                  
-----------------------^
Expecting ':'
```

Comment: Ask the supplier of the JSON to provide valid JSON.  (Of course, it may be that in copy/pasting the example you somehow lost a \ character or two that was escaping a `"` or two.)

Comment: You need change invalid caracter by html code

Comment: Unescaped speech marks, the JSON is broken - they need to be escaped on creation.

Comment: As an aside, this may be helpful. [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "JSON" data string at `Information[0]/story[0]` contains unescaped quotes (`"`).  That's not valid JSON.

Somewhere around here: . . . `proverbial "crazy guy in the fight," at least` . . .

The quotes inside of your data string should instead be escaped (`\"`).

Like this: . . . `proverbial \"crazy guy in the fight,\" at least` . . .

*Furthermore*, the `story[0]` JSON object contains fields without names - also invalid.  You can just put a JSON string inside of curly brackets (`{ "abc" }`). A JSON object is a collection of key-value pairs where they key is a JSON string (`{ "some-key": "abc" }`).

In general, refer to here: http://json.org/

Comment: Thanks that worked. This worked:{
    "Information": [
        {
            "nm": "Earn Goody",
            "st": "y",
            "source": "Internet",
            "story": [
                {
                    "nma": "Earn Goody",
                    "p": [
                        "Paragraph 1 \"crazy guy in the fight,\" sets: 6-2, 1-6, 6-4, in the Round of 16 at Wimbledon on Monday.",
                        "Paragraph 2 text here."
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the story array to contain string values? in that case, remove the curly barces "{}" inside the array.

The other comments on the quoting also apply, but the error message is related to the invalid array format. See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)